# Why Typescript doesn't allow this calculation?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following logic:

There is a multi step form with exactly four steps and a back button. A user can go forward and backwards, but if he is on the first or last step, the back button should go to the previous screen.

Now consider the code made to satisfy that (It was made with React Native, but it can be done similarly independent of the context):

```
const [step, setStep] = useState<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>(1)
// ...
if (step === 1 || step === 4) {
    // exit the screen
} else {
    setStep(step - 1)
}
```

The line inside the `else` block shows `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<2 | 1 | 3 | 4>'. ts(2345)`. However, hovering `step` inside the `else` block gives the type `2 | 3`, which should be fine to subtract 1, since the minimum value possible is 1.

Is this a bug? Am I missing something? How can I write valid code for this use case?

Comment: ① What's `useState`? Could you either tag the question with React or [edit] to make the code a [mre] without such a dependency? ② Assuming I understand your issue without being able to use my IDE on it, this isn't a bug but a missing TS feature; the compiler doesn't do math on numeric literals; see [ms/TS#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) for the relevant feature request.  As for "how can I write valid code" that's a separate question, please [edit] to make it clear what your primary question is.

Comment: I would belive it as an enum. this should explane it for you.

Comment: @jcalz IMO, not worth bringing React into this. It's a simple TS issue. A minimal example would drop the UI framework: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mkGDKGIADgFzwAUAHmQIzwA+8ATA-AMysAsAlPALwA+eADckAS2ABuALAAoUJFgJk6LJmK1WLRh0acZsuWIBmFdUX58+8OvUbnL1nvADec+B-gB6L-BCUxLAwACwQ0MDgQFDkAXz8IHFd3Txx8QiJyBwBaG0luWKA)

Comment: @VLAZ indeed, which is why the question should be [edit]ed not to use React. I'd do the edit myself if Kyomen doesn't mind, but sometimes people *do* mind and then there are edit wars and... well I'd rather just get permission or have them do it.

Comment: @jcalz you can edit it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types don't do math. `step - 1` is type `number` which is broader than `1 | 2 | 3 | 4`.
One path would be to remove the subtraction:

```
const [step, setStep] = useState<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>(1)
// ...
if (step === 1 || step === 4) {
    // exit the screen
} else if (step === 2) {
    setStep(1)
} else {
    setStep(2)
}
```

but that becomes quite easily error prone and is less obvious. In this case I guess I would "help" the compiler by casting

```
const [step, setStep] = useState<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>(1)
// ...
if (step === 1 || step === 4) {
    // exit the screen
} else {
    setStep((step - 1) as 1 | 2 | 3 | 4) // even "as 1 | 2" if you like
}
```

It's also worth creating a type alias to avoid duplicating the type (e.g. `type Steps = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`).